# XCode: link to instance function in comment

Tags: xcode, comments

I'm trying to add some documentation to my project, and I was wondering if it's possible to add a "link" to an instance function in another class within a comment.  Right now I can simply have something like `// see AppDelegate for the response to this notification` and I can command-click on `AppDelegate` to take me to that file, but I'd like to be able to command-click and be taken to a specific function where exactly something like a notification is responded to.

Is this possible?